# Jquery mobile Login Form

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, login-script

I tried to set up a login Form for a mobile Application with Jquery mobile. I can't find the mistake why it is not working. Here is my code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#loginForm').submit(function(){     
              useremail=$("#userEmail").val();
              password=$("#password").val();

            //alert(useremail + " password: " + password);

              $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "login.php",
               data: "email="+useremail+"&password="+password,
               success: function(data){ 
               if (data === 'true') {
                 $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#index", {transition: "slide"});
                }
                else {
                    $( "#error_popup" ).popup("open");
                }  
                }         
              });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

and the login.php file...

```
include("config.php");

session_start(); 
$email = $_POST["email"]; 
$password = md5($_POST["password"]); 
$query = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE email LIKE '$email' AND password LIKE '$password'";
$res = mysqli_query( $db_con, $query );
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($res);

echo $rows;

if($rows == 1) 
    { 
        echo true;
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($res);
        $username = $row[0];
        $_SESSION["username"] = $username; 
    } 
else {
    echo false;
    }
```

I hope someone can help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to add error function to catch if communication error exist..

```
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                showAlert(xhr.statusText, 1);
            }
```

Also try to add this in your ajax request :

async: false,
cashe: false,
dataType: "text",

So , your requst will be :

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#loginForm').submit(function(){     
          useremail=$("#userEmail").val();
          password=$("#password").val();

        //alert(useremail + " password: " + password);

          $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "login.php",
           data: "email="+useremail+"&password="+password,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
           success: function(data){ 
           if (data === 'true') {
             $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#index", {transition: "slide"});
            }
            else {
                $( "#error_popup" ).popup("open");
            }  
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                showAlert(xhr.statusText, 1);
            }         
          });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is still not running. I always get the "error_popup".

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is in ajax settings, you are building **data** as it is **GET** method.
Try to change that part like this.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#loginForm').submit(function(){     
          useremail=$("#userEmail").val();
          password=$("#password").val();

        //alert(useremail + " password: " + password);

          $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "login.php",
           //data: "email="+useremail+"&password="+password,
           data: "{'email': '" + useremail+ "',"'password': '"+password+"'}",
           success: function(data){ 
           if (data === 'true') {
             $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#index", {transition: "slide"});
            }
            else {
                $( "#error_popup" ).popup("open");
            }  
            }         
          });
        return false;
    });
});
```

or even better

```
var DTO = { 'email': useremail, 'password': password};
 var send = JSON.stringify(DTO);
```

and in ajax just put **data:send**

Comment: Thank you :) But still the same problem :(

Comment: Maybe someone knows a better login script? I just need a login area with session for a jqery mobile single page which i want to transform into a mobile app with phonegap.

Comment: what is exactly your problem ..can you read values on server via $_POST["email"] ?

Comment: Yes i can! I always get the "error_popup" and no page transition.

Comment: I am not php guy, but your problem is then on server, look at tutorials jquery ajax +php  (http://www.keyboardninja.eu/webdevelopment/jquery-ajax-call-tutorial), and if you don't already use firebug(http://getfirebug.com/), start using it and monitor your network requests and responses with it